# Como adicionar margens e texto ao gráfico (plot)?

Tags: r, plot, drc

Gostaria de saber como remover as linhas das margens do gráfico no próprio `R` (ex: imagem 1) e adicionar o valor da correlação da curva modelada, com o valor do coeficiente de determinação (R²).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
library(drc)

S.alba.m1 <- drm(DryMatter~Dose, Herbicide, data = S.alba, fct = LL.4())

plot(S.alba.m1)
cor( fitted(S.alba.m1), S.alba$DryMatter^2)
[1] 0.9292864
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por padrão, o `R` considera que sua `plot` cria quatro eixos:

- eixo 1 (equivalente ao eixo x, com escala definida)
- eixo 2 (equivalente ao eixo y, com escala definida)
- eixo 3 (paralelo ao eixo x, sem escala definida)
- eixo 4 (equivalente ao eixo y, sem escala definida)

Em um gráfico tradicional, estes eixos podem ser desligados através do argumento `axes=FALSE`:

```
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, 0.01)
plot(sin(x) ~ x, axes=FALSE, type="l")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fica fácil adicionar os eixos que falta utilizando a função `axis`, na definição que coloquei acima:

```
axis(1)
axis(2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas perceba que os eixos não estão conectados, como se esperaria em um gráfico tradicional. Uma maneira de fazer eles se conectarem é através da função `box`:

```
box(bty="L")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que a função `plot.rcd`, mesmo com o argumento `axes=FALSE`, desenha a box do gráfico:

```
S.alba.m1 <- drm(DryMatter~Dose, Herbicide, data = S.alba, fct = LL.4())
plot(S.alba.m1, axes=FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma maneira de evitar isto é desenhar o gráfico acima, sem os eixos, mas com a box. Em cima da box preta, desenhar uma box branca, com largura igual a três. Assim, a box preta original terá sido "apagada" (na verdade, ela foi apenas sobreposta). Após isto, basta adicionar os eixos e a box unindo eles:

```
box(col="white", lwd=3)
axis(1)
axis(2)
box(bty="L")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por fim, a função `text` coloca qualquer texto em cima de um gráfico. Basta colocar as coordenadas x e y de onde o texto deve aparecer. No caso abaixo, coloquei o texto na posição x=5 e y=1 (o que não quer dizer, em hipótese nenhuma, que este é o melhor lugar para colocar esta informação):

```
text(5, 1, labels=paste("R²=", "0.9293", sep=""))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Observação:** a pergunta foi respondida como perguntada, mas a estatística calculada por `cor(fitted(S.alba.m1), S.alba$DryMatter^2)` **não é** o R^2 da curva ajustada. Este valor calculado é apenas a correlação entre os valores ajustados e o quadrado de `DryMatter`. Iasto nãoo tem nada a ver com o coeficiente de determinação, que deve ser calculado sempre a partir das funções de verossimilhança (exceto no caso da regressão linear simples, que pode ser calculado como o quadrado de uma correlação amostral). Existem muitas formas diferentes de calcular o R^2 em uma regressão logística e utilizar esta fórmula **não é** uma delas.

Comment: Mas uma vez muito obrigado Marcus, não havia percebido que a função que eu estava utilizado serve somente para regressão linear simples, vou buscar uma forma de calcular o coeficiente de determinação para os modelos logísticos através do software R.